# summing the resultant values from sql view as a total

Tags: sql, subquery

I have three tables like this - *Hospital*, *Diagnosstic*  and *Farmacy*.

**Hospital**

```
HospitalID   int
PatientID    int
Due         float
```

**Diagnosstic**

```
DaignosticID   int
PatientID    int
Due         float
```

**Farmacy**

```
FarmacyID   int
PatientID    int
Due         float
```

the *patientID* column are **pk** from *Patient* Table

```
PatientId  int
Patient name  var
```

I have query to show all of the dues of a patient from different table and sum them as total.

I succeeded to retrieve the all dues of a patient but how do I sum them?

My query is:

```
declare @patient int set @patient=1
BEGIN 
  SELECT 
   dbo.Master.Name, 
    dbo.Diagonistic.Due AS DaigiDue, 
    dbo.Farmacy.Due AS FramaDue,            
    dbo.Hospital.Due AS HospiDue 
 FROM dbo.Diagonistic 
 FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Master ON dbo.Diagonistic.PatientId = dbo.Master.PatientId 
 FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Farmacy ON dbo.Master.PatientId = dbo.Farmacy.PatientId 
 FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Hospital ON dbo.Master.PatientId = dbo.Hospital.PatientId 
 where 
   dbo.Master.PatientId= @Patient 
end
```

Comment: what u mean by total due...means sum of all three or sum of inddividual categore(fram,hosp,diag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With this...

```
Declare @Patient Int 
Set @Patient=1
Begin 

    Select 
    dbo.Master.Name, 
    dbo.Diagonistic.Due AS DaigiDue, 
    dbo.Farmacy.Due AS FramaDue,            
    dbo.Hospital.Due AS HospiDue,
    Isnull(dbo.Diagonistic.Due,'0') +  Isnull(dbo.Farmacy.Due,'0') + Isnull(dbo.Hospital.Due,'0') as TotalDue     
    From dbo.Diagonistic 
    Full Outer Join dbo.Master ON dbo.Diagonistic.PatientId = dbo.Master.PatientId 
    Full Outer Join dbo.Farmacy ON dbo.Master.PatientId = dbo.Farmacy.PatientId 
    Full Outer Join dbo.Hospital ON dbo.Master.PatientId = dbo.Hospital.PatientId 
    Where 
        dbo.Master.PatientId= @Patient 

End
```